# Magento 2 - Event sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item removed

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2

I was adding additional details in custom table after **sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item** event in magento1.x. Now I need to do the same in Magento2.x , but As i have searched, this event is removed from Magento2.x. What's the alternative plugin approach for the same?

Thanks

Comment: I post answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Additional Option Using Observer
We can use ***“sales_model_service_quote_submit_before”*** event to copy additional option from quote item.

First of all we need to define it in ***events.xml.*** Write following code in ***events.xml*** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="unique_name" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\OrderItemAdditionalOptions" />
    </event>
</config>
```

After this create observer file and write following code in ***OrderItemAdditionalOptions.php***  file .

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderItemAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            $quoteItems = [];

            // Map Quote Item with Quote Item Id
            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quoteItem) {
                $quoteItems[$quoteItem->getId()] = $quoteItem;
            }

            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
                $quoteItemId = $orderItem->getQuoteItemId();
                $quoteItem = $quoteItems[$quoteItemId];
                $additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options');


                if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
                    // Get Order Item's other options
                    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                    // Set additional options to Order Item
                    $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                    $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // catch error if any
        }
    }
}
```

Set Additional Option Using Plugin

> ***We can use plugin for method convert in class Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem.***

This method is executed when a quote item converts into order item.

First of all define plugin in ***di.xml*** of module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="unique_name" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\ToOrderItem" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

After that create Plugin file and write following code in ***ToOrderItem.php*** file.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as QuoteToOrderItem;

class ToOrderItem
{
    /**
     * aroundConvert
     *
     * @param QuoteToOrderItem $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item
     */
    public function aroundConvert(
        QuoteToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $item,
        $data = []
    ) {
        // Get Order Item
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $data);
        // Get Quote Item's additional Options
        $additionalOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');

        // Check if there is any additional options in Quote Item
        if ($additionalOptions) {
              // Get Order Item’s other options
             $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();

              // Set additional options to Order Item
              $options[‘additional_options’] = json_decode($additionalOptions->getValue());

              $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
          }

        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In magento 2 if you want to convert quote item to order item you need to used this things.

1. Create `fieldset.xml` file at following location.

   app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\fieldset.xml.
2. Put this code in `fieldset.xml`

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0"?> 
>  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
>    <scope id="global">
>     <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_item">
>       <field name="your_fieldname">
>         <aspect name="to_order"/>
>       </field>
>     </fieldset>
>   </scope> 
> </config>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps You can use the event **sales_model_service_quote_submit_before**.
In it are available order models and quote.